# Unity5 Error while saving blame file

Tags: android, sdk, unity-game-engine

I updated an existing project from Unity 5.6.0 to 5.6.1 and a error I've never encountered appeared. I've looked around but couldn't find anything about it. The consol text mentions Tools and AndroidSDK so I made sure to update everything from Android Studio but the issue is not fixed. SDK & JDK are setup correctly. I still can't build (Nothing has changed except the update and the game has been working well for months). If anyone could give me pointers on how to fix this, it'd be awesome. (Also, the error only happens in this project)
Here is the consol text that appears :

```
Error: Error while saving blame file, build will continue   
Error: Le préfixe "tools" de l'attribut "tools:overrideLibrary" associé à un type d'élément "uses-sdk" n'est pas lié
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

(The french part is weird since my whole system is in English, but it means : Error: The "tools" prefix of the "Tools:overrideLibrary" associated with a type of element "uses-sdk" is not linked).
Then an other error appears, but I think it is related to the first :

```
AndroidSDKToolsException: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.DetectErrorsAndWarnings (System.String logMessages, System.String errorMsg)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String[] sdkToolCommand, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
 UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.MergeManifests (System.String target, System.String mainManifest, System.String[] libraryManifests, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.MergeManifests (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context, System.String targetManifest, System.String mainManifest)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.GenerateManifest.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
 UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
 UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **AndroidManifest.xml**  add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to `manifest` tag. It should look something like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.unity3d.player"
 android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
```